# Using CI to Build Interdependent Projects in Isolation

Tags: continuous-integration

So, I have an interesting situation.  I have a group that is interested in using CI to help catch developer errors.  Great - we are all for that.  The problem I am having wrapping my head around things is that they want to build interdependent projects isolated from one another.

For example, we have a solution for our common/shared libraries that contains multiple projects, some of which depend on others in the solution.  I would expect that if someone submits a change to one of the projects in the solution, the CI server would try to build the *solution*.  After all, the solution is aware of dependencies and will build things, optimized, in the correct order.

Instead, they have broken out each project and are attempting to build them independently, without regard for dependencies.  This causes other errors because dependent DLLs might not yet exist(!) and a possible chicken-and-egg problem if related changes were made in two or more projects.

This results in a lot of emails about broken builds (one for each project), even if the last set of changes did not really break anything!  When I raised this issue, I was told that this was a known issue and the CI server would "rebuild things a few times to work out the dependencies!"

This sounds like a bass-ackwards way to do CI builds.  But maybe that is because I am older and ignorant of newer trends - so, as anyone known of a CI setup that builds interdependent projects independently?  Any for what good reason?

Oh, and they are expecting us to use the build outputs from the CI process, and each built DLL gets a potentially *different version number*.  So we no longer have a single version number for the output of all related DLLs.  The best we can ascertain is that something was built on a specific calendar day.

I seem to be unable to convince them that this is **A Bad Thing**.
So, what am I missing here?

Thanks!

Peace!

Answer (score 1):

I second your opinion.

You risk spending more time dealing with the unnecessary noise than with the actual issues. And repeating portions of the CI verification pipeline only extends the overall CI execution time, which goes against the CI goal of reducing the feedback loop.

If anything you should try to bring as many dependent projects as possible (ideally all of them) under the same CI umbrella, to maximize the benefit of fast feedback of breakages/regressions on any part of the system as a whole.

Personally I also advocate using a gating CI system (based on pre-commit verifications) to **prevent** regressions rather than just **detecting** them and relying on human intervention for repairs.